# How Do I get a vector from an angle, opposite of atan2?

Tags: python

like the title says, I would like to get a vector from an angle. This would just be a ratio for example with an angle of 45 the vector would be (1,1). is there any way to do this?

Comment: You mean `tan`?

Comment: is there a way to convert that output into a ratio though?

Comment: cos and sin are your friends

Comment: A ratio is one number divided by another. The ratio 1/1 is equal to 1.0, and that is the tan of 45°.

Comment: [Heading vector corresponding to an angle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180874/convert-angle-radians-to-a-heading-vector)

Answer (score -2):

The inverse of `math.atan2(y, x)` is `math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle)`. The angle has to be in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) rather than degrees.

```py
>>> import math
>>> angle = math.pi / 3
>>> angle
1.0471975511965976
>>> x, y = math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle)
>>> x, y
(0.5000000000000001, 0.8660254037844386)
>>> math.atan2(y, x)
1.0471975511965976
```